# Porting issue with Docker

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

Hey I tried running the command

```
sudo docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py"
```

from the tutorial but I keep getting the error

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container.
```

I downloaded the image fine but the trouble occurs whenever I try to run it. I checked the port `sudo docker port (name)` and nothing shows up. I'm guessing the issue is that the PORTS aren't being set up properly. I have a mac and I'm using vmware with ubuntu and I downloaded the ubuntu set up for docker.

Is there anyway to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post `docker images | grep training` ?

Comment: Yep, this is the output:
`8:training/webapp     latest              31fa814ba25a        9 months ago        278.8 MB`

Comment: ok, so now let's check the logs `docker logs 31f`

Comment: Another problem: `FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: No such container: 31f `

Comment: Yes, it is not the image that we should check, `docker events --since '2015-03-04'`

Comment: Sorry its kinda messy: `2015-03-04T16:03:41.000000000Z 9e09fc2742d1a5e61d4453ca877db4709441432ea25a3b348a453ad412080da3: (from training/webapp:latest) create`                                                           
`2015-03-04T16:03:41.000000000Z 9e09fc2742d1a5e61d4453ca877db4709441432ea25a3b348a453ad412080da3: (from training/webapp:latest) die`

Comment: So it dies immediately, may be you should restart docker, `kill -9`of the docker process, and then restart in debug mode `docker -D -d`

Comment: Is there a command to restart docker? I tried debug mode and was returned with `INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)`   
`FATA[0000] pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid `

Comment: extract from http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon I see `To run the daemon with debug output, use docker -d -D`

Comment: I t seems you forgot to stop the docker daemon first, the `kill -9`of the docker process

Comment: Ok I executed `kill -9` with no problems and tried to run `docker -d -D` but the same error showed up again `INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)`   
`FATA[0000] pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid `